# Dictionary with functions versus dictionary with class

Tags: python-3.x, class, dictionary

I'm creating a game where i have the data imported from a database, but i have a little problem...

Currently i get a copy of the data as a dictionary, which i need to pass as argument to my GUI, however i also need to process some data, like in this example:

I get the data as a dict (I've created the UseDatabase context manager and is working):

```
def get_user(name: str, passwd: str):
    user = {}
    user['name'] = name
    user['passwd'] = passwd

    with UseDatabase() as cursor:
        _SQL = "SELECT id, cash, ruby FROM user WHERE name='Admin' AND password='adminpass'"

        cursor.execute(_SQL)
        res = cursor.fetchall()

    if res:
        user['id'] = res[0][0]
        user['cash'] = res[0][1]
        user['ruby'] = res[0][2]
        return user
    return res

                   .
                   .
                   .

def get_activities():
    with UseDatabase() as cursor:
         _SQL = "SELECT * FROM activities WHERE user_id='2'"

        cursor.execute(_SQL)
        res = cursor.fetchall()

    if res:
        ids = [i[0] for i in res]
        activities = {}
        for i in res:
            activities[i[0]] = {'title':i[1],'unlock':i[2],'usr_progress':i[3]}
        return (ids, activities)
    return res
```

Need it as a dict in my GUI ("content" argument):

```
class SideBar:
    def __init__(self, screen: 'pygame.display.set_mode()', box_width: int, box_height: int, content: dict, font: 'font = pygame.font.Font()'):
        #content dict: {id: {'title':'','unlock':'','usr_progress':''},...}
        self.box_width = box_width
        self.box_height = box_height
        self.box_per_screen = screen.get_height() // box_height
        self.content = content
        self.current_box = 1
        self.screen = screen
        self.font = font

        self.generate_bar()

    def generate_bar (self):
        active = [i for i in self.content.keys() if i in range(self.current_box, self.current_box+self.box_per_screen)]
        for i in range(self.box_per_screen):
            gfxdraw.box(self.screen,pygame.Rect((0,i*self.box_height),(self.screen.get_width()/3,self.screen.get_height()/3)),(249,0,0,170))
            self.screen.blit(self.font.render(str(active[i]) + ' - ' + self.content[active[i]]['title'], True, (255,255,255)),(10,i*self.box_height+4))

        for i in range(self.box_per_screen):
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen,(50,0,0),pygame.Rect((0,i*self.box_height),(self.screen.get_width()/3,self.screen.get_height()/3)),2)
```

But still need to make some changes in the data:

```
def unlock_act(act_id):
    if user['cash'] >= activities[act_id]['unlock'] and activities[act_id]['usr_progress'] == 0:
        user['cash'] -= activities[act_id]['unlock']
        activities[act_id]['usr_progress'] = 1
```

So the question is: in this situation should i keep a copy of the data as dict, and create a class with it plus the methods i need or use functions to edit the data inside the dict?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Could you provide a more complete code example?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you just asking if `unlock_act` should be a method on some class or if it should stay a function? I'm not sure there's an obvious answer to that. Either style of code could work. Which is better is largely a matter of opinion. A bigger question is, how do you plan to re-sync the modified data with your database?

Comment: It would depend... If i created a class i could just create a save method to pass the class attributes, with a dict i would create one more function to save the data in it. By the way is there any performance difference between methods and functions? Thanks